# refreshcapex in LWC is not triggered when I am calling it from child component

Tags: lwc-wire-adapter, refreshapex

```
<c-datatablelwc config={config} onrowaction={handleRowAction} >
</c-datatablelwc>
```

`datatablelwc` is a utility LWC which holds the standard datatable component, actually it is also has one more child component where I have custom types for Call-to-dial..

```
<c-custom-lightning-datatable key-field="Id"
    data={recordsListInPage}
    columns={tableProps.columns}
    selected-rows={tableProps.selectedRows}...
</c-custom-lightning-datatable>
```

so in my `c-datatablelwc.js` I have method which populates data to parent component which displays data.. but after an edit I want to call `refreshApex`, but how to call refresh apex from parent component.

Comment: From which component you are querying data, parent or child?

Comment: I am querying data from child component.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `@api` method in the child, so that can be called from the parent.

**In child js.**

```
@api refreshData(){
    refreshApex(this.wiredResult);
}
```

Now in the parent, you can call the same method whenever needed.

**In parent js.**

```
this.getElementsByTagName("c-custom-lightning-datatable")[0].refreshData();
```